# Magento 2: add js file, but I can't find my file in static folder

Tags: magento2, custom, requirejs, js-css

I add js file in my module using the requirejs, but the requirejs can't load the file and i get this error:

> require.js:1895 GET (my_ip)/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/SaturTheme/it_IT/SliderHome/js/materialize.js

If I open this link I get this stacktrace error:

```
The "/var/www/html/magento2/" file doesn't exist or not a file

    0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(146): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->assertIsFile(false)
    1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/MaterializationStrategy/Symlink.php(30): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->createSymlink(false, 'frontend/Magent...', Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write))
    2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(66): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink->publishFile(Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write), Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write), false, 'frontend/Magent...')
    3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
    4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(109): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
    5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
    6 /var/www/html/magento2/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
    7 {main}
```

I tried also to run this command, but nothing change:

> php bin/magento --ansi setup:static-content:deploy it_IT

Comment: hey, can you give a bit more details please?  
1. Could you share the folder structure of your module and the 
requirers-config.js file content?  
2. How are you calling this js file. from a phtml?

Comment: Have you added correct file path on requirejs file?

Answer (score 0):

you have to first delete `pub/static` folder all content.

Run Command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Remove var folder from root.

Clear Browser cache.

Refresh page your js file is getting inside browser.

Comment: you shouldn't remove .htaccess if you are using apache

Comment: No, the whole `pub/static` folder should never be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your JS code (or at least the require JS dependency part) please? If your file name/paths are correct this should help:

1. Delete `pub/static/frontend`
2. Delete `pub/static/requirejs`
3. Delete `var/view_preprocessed`
4. Clear Magento caches

Do not delete the whole `pub/static` folder or you will run into problems.

Also if you are in developer mode (you should be for development) running the static-content deploy command is a waste of time as the files are symlinked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your module's js file placed as per below location, If not then correct.

```
YourModule/view/frontend/web/js/materialize.js

-> After that you should run deploy command for your language (in case not in en_US)
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT

-> Flush cache and set proper permission to var and pub/static directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you follow all the required steps in this tutorial.
https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-javascript-module/